# ¿Cómo cambiar el formato de campo fecha en Laravel? No estoy usando created_at es un campo normal de mi DB

Tags: laravel

El formato que quiero cambiar es el del campo fecha_ingreso es tipo date muestra Y-m-d y quiero que muestre d-m-Y

**Mi Vista:**

```
public function index()
    {
        //
        $datos = Materiales::join('proveedores', 'proveedores.id_proveedor', '=', 'materiales.id_proveedor')
        ->get(['materiales.id_material','proveedores.razon_social', 'materiales.codigo', 'materiales.nombre', 'materiales.tipo',
        'materiales.descripcion', 'materiales.precio', 'materiales.rebaje', 'materiales.fecha_ingreso']);
        return view('Materiales.index', compact('datos'));
    }
```

**Mi index.blade:**

```
<tbody>
        @foreach ($datos as $dato)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                <td>{{ $dato->razon_social }}</td>
                <td>{{ $dato->codigo }}</td>
                <td>{{ $dato->nombre }}</td>
                <td>{{ $dato->tipo }}</td>
                <td>{{ $dato->descripcion }}</td>
                <td>{{ $dato->precio }}</td>
                <td>{{ $dato->rebaje }}</td>
                <td>{{ $dato->fecha_ingreso }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ url('/Materiales/'.$dato->id_material.'/edit') }}" class="btn btn-warning">
                        Editar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Mando a llamar mis datos con el Join

Comment: No se si comprendí muy bien lo que estas buscando pero si lo que quieres es solo cambiar el formato al momento de mostrar la fecha lo puedes hacer con $dato->fecha_ingreso->format('d-m-Y') si tu campo es una instacia de Carbon,

Comment: Quiero cambiar el formato de la fecha, que muestre en mi index d-m-Y y no como lo arroja por defecto Y-m-d. Como agrego la instancia o como sería? Ya que me al añadir format me arroja el error Call to a member function format() on string

Comment: En tu modelo puedes hacer un cast de ese atributo y decir que será una instancia datetime. Ya laravel se encargaría de convertirla en carbon y que pudieras usarla como una instancia de la misma

Comment: Exacto como dijo @gaidyjg, puedes utilizar el casting 
```protected $casts = [
    'fecha_ingreso ' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',
];
```
esa seria la manera mas limpia de hacerlo otra manera es desde el controlador 
```$tempDate = Carbon::parse($datos['fecha_ingreso']);
$datos['fecha_ingreso'] = $tempDate->format('d-m-Y')

 return view('Materiales.index', compact('datos'));```

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios encontre la solucion directo en el index Carbon\Carbon::parse($dato->fecha_ingreso)->format('d-m-Y') asi quedo llamando la libreria carbon y parseando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en la vista has directamente esto:

{{date('d-m-Y',strtotime($fecha))}} //la variable fecha la cambias por tu campo fecha

eso te dara la fecha en dia-mes-año, si le quieres agregar por ejemplo la hora es igual solo agregas lo siguiente

{{date('d-m-Y h:i:s',strtotime($fecha))}}

Comment: Gracias esto fue algo similar que me ayudo a solucionar eso, sabía que era algo así pero cuando buscaba solo me arrojaban resultados con metodo Carbon. Al final quedo así: 

Carbon\Carbon::parse($dato->fecha_ingreso)->format('d-m-Y') 

Fue con libreria carbon pero parseando.

Comment: Porque Carbon es lo más inmediato si usas Laravel, además que como te dije para eso están los casts